# How do I solve the staircase problem on Hacker rank

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

So, I'm trying to do the staircase problem in hacker rank, I'm trying to achieve it with C

The problem : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/staircase/problem

```
int i,j,k;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=i;j<n;j++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
    for(k=0;k<=i;k++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

}

But all the test cases are failing for the following code, any input would be really helpful :)

Comment: Probably it does not like the newline in the last line?

Comment: @Freeze Why is the assignment called problem? I do not see any problem.:)

Comment: _The last line is not preceded by any spaces._ <- In your code, the last line is preceded by one space. Use `j=i+1`

Comment: Thanks @Ctx, that solved the issue :)

Answer (score 2):

```
void staircase(int n)
{
    for(int step = 1; step <= n; step++)
    {
        for(int spaces = n - step; spaces; spaces--)
        {
            putchar(' ');
        }
        for(int star = 0; star < step; star++)
        {
            putchar('#');
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how would you solve, but I would do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 4; 
    for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
        printf("%*s", i - 1 , ""); // print i - 1 number of spaces
        for (int j = n - i + 1; j > 0; j--) 
            printf("#"); // printing n - i + 1 number of '#'
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Problem Solved,

Answer (score 1):

From the requirement:

> Note: The last line must have 0 spaces in it.

Now change `printf(" ");` to something like `printf("O");` in your code
and you will see what the problem is about

Comment: This has got to be the misunderstanding of the day ;) "0 spaces" means "no spaces"

Comment: What does "sth" mean?

Comment: @S.S.Anne short for "something"

Comment: @Ctx What did I misunderstand? Requirement says that there should be 0 spaces, and I recommend that he should replace his space with some other character so he can see that he actually got a space there

Comment: @Odysseus As I said, the misunderstanding of the day

Comment: @Ctx I think you didnt get my point :) 
I dont want to solve it by replacing the spaces - spaces should be used for sure. But I suggested he did not see that he has got a preceding space in his last line.

Comment: @Odysseus Yes, you are correct!

Comment: Well then I don't know why I got voted down

Comment: @Odysseus I didn't. But I didn't vote up either, because this is not really a solution, looks more like a comment

Comment: @Ctx Thats' true but I dont think delivering a complete solution is the appropriate way in this case either

Comment: @Odysseus ok, ok... voted all up since I do not really understand the downvotes.

Comment: @Ctx Well thanks but i just wanted to know the reason ;) Its annoying if someone thinks sth is wrong/unclear but does not tell it. But that's not up to you then anyway

Answer (score 1):

In this loop

```
for(j=i;j<n;j++)
{
    printf(" ");
}
```

there is outputted one redundant space.

Also according to the assignment presented at the provided reference n shall be between (0, 100]. Maybe you should check in the function that outputs the pattern that the passed argument has a value in this range.

And if I am not mistaken the program should be written in C++. Something like the following

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

// Complete the staircase function below.
void staircase(int n) 
{
    const int MAX_VALUE = 100;

    if ( 0 < n && n <= MAX_VALUE )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            std::cout << std::setw( n - i )
                      << std::setfill( ' ' )
                      << '#';
            std::cout << std::setw( i + 1 )
                      << std::setfill( '#' )
                      << '\n';
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    staircase(n);

    return 0;
}
```

In C the completed program template can look like

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* readline();

// Complete the staircase function below.
void staircase(int n) 
{
    const int MAX_VALUE = 100;

    if ( 0 < n && n <= MAX_VALUE )
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%*c", n - i, '#' );
            for ( size_t j = 0; j < i; j++ ) putchar( '#' );
            putchar( '\n' );
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    char* n_endptr;
    char* n_str = readline();
    int n = strtol(n_str, &n_endptr, 10);

    if (n_endptr == n_str || *n_endptr != '\0') { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }

    staircase(n);

    return 0;
}

char* readline() {
    size_t alloc_length = 1024;
    size_t data_length = 0;
    char* data = malloc(alloc_length);

    while (true) {
        char* cursor = data + data_length;
        char* line = fgets(cursor, alloc_length - data_length, stdin);

        if (!line) { break; }

        data_length += strlen(cursor);

        if (data_length < alloc_length - 1 || data[data_length - 1] == '\n') { break; }

        size_t new_length = alloc_length << 1;
        data = realloc(data, new_length);

        if (!data) { break; }

        alloc_length = new_length;
    }

    if (data[data_length - 1] == '\n') {
        data[data_length - 1] = '\0';
    }

    data = realloc(data, data_length);

    return data;
}
```

Perhaps instead of the test

```
    if ( 0 < n && n <= MAX_VALUE )
```

you should use an assert.

Comment: You can indeed choose from over 20 languages and solve the problem in any of these

Comment: @Ctx At the provided reference I saw that there is suggested to enter a C++ code.

Comment: There is an input area below and a "Change theme" dropdown field, where you can choose

Comment: @Ctx I placed also a C program.

Comment: Fine ;) Still, I can upvote only once, sorry ;)